# Cuda program not working for more than 1024 threads

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia

My program is of `Odd-even merge sort` and it's not working for more than 1024 threads.

I have already tried increasing the **block size** to 100 but it still not working for more than 1024 threads.

I'm using **Visual Studio 2012** and I have **Nvidia Geforce 610M**. This is my program

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include <random>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <driver_types.h >


__global__ void odd(int *arr,int n){
    int i=threadIdx.x;
    int temp;
    if(i%2==1&&i<n-1){
        if(arr[i]>arr[i+1])
        {
            temp=arr[i];
            arr[i]=arr[i+1];
            arr[i+1]=temp;
        }
    }
}

__global__ void even(int *arr,int n){
    int i=threadIdx.x;
    int temp;
    if(i%2==0&&i<n-1){
        if(arr[i]>arr[i+1])
        {
            temp=arr[i];
            arr[i]=arr[i+1];
            arr[i+1]=temp;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int SIZE,k,*A,p,j;
    int *d_A;
    float time;

    printf("Enter the size of the array\n");
    scanf("%d",&SIZE);
    A=(int *)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc(&d_A,SIZE*sizeof(int));
    for(k=0;k<SIZE;k++)
    A[k]=rand()%1000;


    cudaMemcpy(d_A,A,SIZE*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if(SIZE%2==0)
        p=SIZE/2;
    else
        p=SIZE/2+1;


    for(j=0;j<p;j++){
        even<<<3,SIZE>>>(d_A,SIZE);
        if(j!=p-1)
            odd<<<3,SIZE>>>(d_A,SIZE);
        if(j==p-1&&SIZE%2==0)
            odd<<<1,SIZE>>>(d_A,SIZE);
    }


    cudaMemcpy(A,d_A,SIZE*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    for(k=0;k<SIZE;k++)
        printf("%d ",A[k]);


    free(A);
    cudaFree(d_A);

    getch();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CUDA threadblocks are [limited](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications__technical-specifications-per-compute-capability) to 1024 threads (or 512 threads, for cc 1.x gpus).  The size of the threadblock is indicated in the second kernel configuration parameter in the kernel launch:

```
    even<<<3,SIZE>>>(d_A,SIZE);
             ^^^^
```

So when you enter a `SIZE` value greater than 1024, this kernel will not launch.

You're getting no indication of this because you're not doing [proper cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) which is always a good idea any time you're having trouble with a CUDA code.  You can also, as a quick test, run your code with `cuda-memcheck` to look for API errors.